# assertion failure when trying to test a model with the pinocchio library

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use the Pinocchio library for 3D animations;  I create my skeleton; then try to make a pinocchio model for the skeleton.  Then I try to test out the model with [code from here](https://gepettoweb.laas.fr/doc/stack-of-tasks/pinocchio/master/doxygen-html/md_doc_b-examples_a-model.html), and I get an assertion failure.

This is my code; I didn't include where I got the skeleton struct from, but for this test case I made it from a mixamorig.

```
using namespace glm;

struct Skeleton
{
    ~Skeleton();

    vec3 * translation;
    quat * rotation;
    int * parent; // guaranteed: parent[i] < i
    size_t size;
};

pinocchio::Model MakeModel(Skeleton const& skeleton)
{
    pinocchio::Model model;

    for(auto i = 0u; i < skeleton.size; ++i)
    {
        vec3 const& t = skeleton.translation[i];
        quat const& r = skeleton.rotation[i];

        auto translation = pinocchio::SE3::LinearType(t.x, t.y, t.z);
        auto rotation    = pinocchio::SE3::Quaternion(r.w, r.x, r.y, r.z);
    
//-1 is no parent; so i guess it should be 0 because thats the root parent in pinocchio?
        model.addJoint  (skeleton.parent[i]+1,
            pinocchio::JointModelRX(), // i dunno what any of these are yet
            pinocchio::SE3(rotation, translation),
            std::to_string(i));
    }

    TestModel(model);
    return model
}

void TestModel(pinocchio::Model & model)
{
// test the model!
    pinocchio::Data data(model);

    Eigen::VectorXd q = pinocchio::randomConfiguration(model);
// everything is inf
    std::cout << "q: " << q.transpose() << std::endl;

//assertion failure (this data doesn't belong to the model)
    forwardKinematics(model,data,q);

  // Print out the placement of each joint of the kinematic tree
    for(int joint_id = 0; joint_id < model.njoints; ++joint_id)
        std::cout << std::setw(24) << std::left
              << model.names[joint_id] << ": "
              << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
              << data.oMi[joint_id].translation().transpose()
              << std::endl;

}
```

The output is this:

```
q: inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf
Engine: void pinocchio::forwardKinematics(const pinocchio::Model&, pinocchio::Data&, const Eigen::Matrix&): Assertion `model.check(data) && "data is not consistent with model."' failed.
```

Is there some step I need to do to finalize the model before I can use it in the data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this happens because `parent[i] < i` isn’t a strong enough guarantee.  The solution is to ensure that the nodes are in depth first order. If any of them is in breadth-first-order for example, it will produce the error that the data does not belong to the model even though it does.